# Capturing image of motion with SimpleCV motion detection

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 to detect motion using SimpleCV, and then when motion is detected an image should be taken. I'm using a USB camera. This is the code I'm using:

```
from SimpleCV import *
import os

cam = Camera()
threshold = 5.0 # if mean exceeds this amount do something

while True:
    previous = cam.getImage() #grab a frame
    time.sleep(0.5) #wait for half a second
    current = cam.getImage() #grab another frame
    diff = current - previous
    matrix = diff.getNumpy()
    mean = matrix.mean()



    if mean >= threshold:
        time.sleep(2)
        os.popen("fswebcam -d /dev/video0 -r 352x280 
        /home/pi/Desktop/image.jpg")
        print "Motion Detected"
```

When motion is detected, it prints "Motion Detection", so that's working, but no image is taken. I tried running fswebcam -d /dev/video0 -r 352x280 
            /home/pi/Desktop/image.jpg in the terminal and it worked fine. Also, when I ran the code to take an image in python by itself, it also worked, but in the if statement it won't work. I tried running the program from the terminal, and again the motion detection works but I get this error:
Error selecting input 0
VIDEO_S_Input: Device or resource busy

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

It is mentioned in the documentation that the resource will be locked once you have an active instance of Camera.

SimpleCV Camera Class documentation is here:

```
class Camera(FrameSource):
    """
    **SUMMARY**
    The Camera class is the class for managing input from a basic camera.  Note
    that once the camera is initialized, it will be locked from being used
    by other processes.  You can check manually if you have compatible devices
    on linux by looking for /dev/video* devices.
```

As your resource is locked, it is unavailable or remains busy for fswebcam to access.

Instead as you already have an instance of camera `cam`, use it to capture image as below:

```
img = cam.getImage()
img.save("motion.jpg")
```

**Alternative Solution**

you can just do `del cam.capture` before below line:

`os.popen("fswebcam -d /dev/video0 -r 352x280 /home/pi/Desktop/image.jpg")`